# How does scanf() really work?

Tags: c, scanf, stdio

On Windows,

```
char c;
int i;

scanf("%d", &i);
scanf("%c", &c);
```

The computer skips to retrieve character from console because '\n' is remaining on buffer.
However, I found out that the code below works well.

```
char str[10];
int i;

scanf("%d", &i);
scanf("%s", str);
```

Just like the case above, '\n' is remaining on buffer but why scanf successfully gets the string from console this time?

Comment: Need a little bit more input here. What are you typing in the console? What do you want it to get? There is no reason why the above code shouldn't work as intended, but that depends on what is intended.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the gcc man page (I don't have Windows handy):

%c: matches a fixed number of characters, always.  The maximum field width says how
many characters to read; if you don't specify the maximum, the default is 1.  It also does not skip over initial whitespace characters.

%s: matches a string of non-whitespace characters. **It skips and discards initial 
whitespace, but stops when it encounters more whitespace after having read something.**
[ This clause should explain the behaviour you are seeing. ]

Answer (score 2):

Having trouble understanding the question, but scanf ignores all whitespace characters. `n` is a whitespace character. If you want to detect when user presses enter you should use fgets.

```
fgets(str, 10, stdin);
```

Comment: sry for bad eng :( I think I should've use word 'get' rather than 'retrieve'. I just confused the meanings.